# Set attribute "placeholder" for struts1.2 html:text input tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, struts, struts-1

I am trying to set attribute **placeholder** for Struts1.2  tag on IE browser.

```
<html:text styleId="fname_" property="fname" />
```

and m applying js as follows

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#fname_").attr("placeholder", "Testtest");
});
```

And this is what HTML i am getting

```
<input name="fname" id="fname_" placeholder="Testtest"/>
```

but its not working,not reflecting. Is there any solution for Struts1.2.

Thank u.

Comment: Seems as though there your problem isn't reproducible: http://jsfiddle.net/kLqvcskq/ -- Do you get any errors in your console? Are you referencing jQuery?

Comment: @George i m not getting any error on console too.

Comment: Did you try it on load event?

Comment: @RomanC can u please explain me? You mean onLoad to call this function ?

Comment: @RomanC its not working on window.load.

Comment: Ok, then remove it, struts1 is deprecated.

Comment: Personally I'd just alter the TLD to allow arbitrary attributes.

Comment: @DaveNewton can you please brief it, how you resolved it?